# setText Null Pointer for TextView Array

Tags: android

I've stared at this for about an hour and cannot figure out why the TextView is null.

I've defined it:

```
TextView[] tvEvidenceID;
```

Initialised it:

```
int x = cursorEvidence.getCount();
tvEvidenceID = new TextView[x];


 do {
                    int i = 0;
                    tvEvidenceID[i].setId(i);
                    tvEvidenceID[i].setText("Evidence ID: " + cursorEvidence.getString(cursorEvidence.getColumnIndex("_id")));
                    tvEvidenceID[i].setPadding(50, 50, 0, 0);
                    tvEvidenceID[i].setTextColor(getColor(R.color.white));
                    linearLayout.addView(tvEvidenceID[i]);
                    i++;
    }
 while (cursorEvidence.moveToNext());
```

Stack trace caused by:

```
 Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.TextView.setId(int)' on a null object reference
```

Comment: but, you haven't assigned a value

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You created the array, but not the objects inside the array.
Just add `tvEvidenceID[i] = new TextView(context);`

```
do {
                int i = 0;
                tvEvidenceID[i] = new TextView(context);
                tvEvidenceID[i].setId(i);
                tvEvidenceID[i].setText("Evidence ID: " + cursorEvidence.getString(cursorEvidence.getColumnIndex("_id")));
                tvEvidenceID[i].setPadding(50, 50, 0, 0);
                tvEvidenceID[i].setTextColor(getColor(R.color.white));
                linearLayout.addView(tvEvidenceID[i]);
                i++;
}
while (cursorEvidence.moveToNext());
```

Comment: Awesome, thank you! I knew it'd end up being 1 line of code. I think I need to give up Android after uni...